# CUDA: Global Memory Access Address

Tags: c++, cuda

Is it possible to see the address of Global Memory accessed by a thread during run time?

I know it will create a lot of overhead, but I would like to see what elements are being accessed. I think it will help me understand how the coalescing mechanism is implemented.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA thread code largely follows C and C++ syntax patterns.  So you can easily print out the numerical value of a pointer in kernel code:

```
printf("pval = %p\n", my_pointer);
```

If you wanted to do this across threads in a CUDA kernel, you could do:

```
__global__ void my_kernel(int *data){
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  printf("thread: %d, pointer: %p, value: %d\n", idx, &(data[idx]), data[idx]);
}
```

or similar.  Obviously this will create large amounts of output if you use large numbers of threads, and be aware that in-kernel `printf` uses a buffer of limited size.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I can just do some simple pointer arithmetic to see when the accesses are 'not' coalesced (for e.g. non-unit strides and some such) and just print out that.